# Does $\text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}(Y)$ imply $\text{Corr}(X,Y) = 1$?

Tags: correlation, variance

If variance(X) = variance(Y), is the correlation between X and Y equal to 1, i.e., $\text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}(Y) \implies \text{Corr}(X,Y) = 1$?

Comment: What if $Y=-X$? What if $Y$ and $X$ have the same distribution but are independent?

Answer (score 6):

A more intuitive approach here:

We know that the correlation is equal to one only when there's a linear relationship between variables, *i.e.* $Y = a \cdot X + b$.

The equality of variances leads to $\text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}(Y) = a^2 \cdot \text{Var}(X) \therefore |a| =1$

So correlation will be $\pm1$ (given equal variances) whenever $Y$ is equal to $\pm X$  plus a constant. Any other association between $X$ and $Y$ will not lead to $\rho_{X,Y} = \pm1$.

Answer (score 2):

The stated property can be assessed by manipulating the following equations:

$$
\begin{align}
V(X + Y)  &= V(X) + V(Y) + 2 Cov(X, Y) & (1) \\
Cov(X, Y) &= Corr(X, Y) \sqrt{V(X)V(Y)} & (2)
\end{align}
$$

If you set $V(X) = V(Y)$, plug $(2)$ into $(1)$ and isolate the correlation, you get

$$
\begin{align}
Corr(X, Y) &= \frac{V(X + Y) - V(X) - V(Y)}{2\sqrt{V(X)V(Y)}} \\
&= \frac{V(X + Y) - 2V(X)}{2V(X)} \\
&= \frac{V(X + Y)}{2V(X)} - 1.
\end{align}
$$

If $Corr(X, Y) = 1$, then

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{V(X + Y)}{2V(X)} - 1 &= 1 \\
V(X + Y) &= 4V(X)\\
V(X + Y) &= V(2X),
\end{align}
$$

which implies $X = Y$. Hence, $V(X) = V(Y) \implies Corr(X, Y) = 1$ if, and only if, $X = Y$.

Comment: You formulated your answers in terms of $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ being equal to one. The question, though, is about correlation being equal to 1, there's a difference in scale.

Comment: @Firebug, sorry, you're right. I'll edit it.

Comment: @RichardHardy, duly noted, thanks for the encouragement!

Comment: This is a useful job, and you certainly deserve an acknowledgement :)

Comment: $X$ doesn't need to be exactly equal to $Y$, it can be simply a constant shift, resulting in the same variance and also correlation equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

My take would be the following.

$$\begin{align}
\text{Corr}(X,Y)&=\frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)}}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[
Y]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)}}\\
\end{align}$$

So, if we let $\text{Var}(Y)=\text{Var}(X)$:

$$\begin{align}
\text{Corr}(X,Y)&=\frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)}}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[
Y]}{\text{Var}(X)}\\
\end{align}$$

This can only equal 1 if:

$$\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]=\text{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]-\mathbb{E}[X]^{2}$$

It is not sufficient to say that if $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]$, then this is satisfied. We would also need $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]$ or $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[Y^{2}]$.

Therefore, if $\text{Var}(Y)=\text{Var}(X)$ **and** $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]$ **and**:

$$\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]$$

$$\textbf{or:}$$

$$\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[Y^{2}]$$

then it would suffice to say $\text{Corr}(X,Y)=1$ (i.e. the conditions I provided above are sufficient, however considering the example in the comments below, they are not necessary).

Comment: Consider $X = \{-1, 0, 1\}$ and $Y = \{0, 1, 2\}$. $\text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}(Y) = 1$ and also $\rho_{X,Y} = 1$, but $\mathbb{E}(X) \neq \mathbb{E}(Y)$.

Comment: @Firebug Yes I don't know how useful my answer is. I guess it requires less conditions than stating $X$ must equal $Y$.